# Fabric Js Drag One Image On another

Tags: javascript, jquery, z-index, fabricjs, drag

I have integrated Fabric Js,and its working fine but i have one query,When i add multiple images i can't drag one image over another and the last added image stays on top,can their position be changed? I found one fiddle its working fine
but it has no images and dynamically generated Element bars.

```
var canvas = window.__canvas = new fabric.Element('drawing_area');

        $(".vb_image li a img, .vb_frame_slider, .vb_quote_slider, .vb_graphic_slider").click(function(e){

           var target = e.target || e.srcElement; 

            fabric.Image.fromURL(target.src, function(oImg) {
                canvas.add(oImg);
                oImg.scaleToWidth(200);
                canvas.centerObjectH(oImg).centerObjectV(oImg);
                oImg.setCoords();
                canvas.renderAll();


              });
        });
```

Here is some working fiddle i found but i can not implement this thing on images.
http://jsfiddle.net/RRv3g/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the image you're dragging to be on top of the other images you can use `image.moveTo(index)` or more simply `image.bringToFront()`.

```
fabric.Image.fromURL(imageUrl, function(image) {
    image.on('selected', function() {
        image.bringToFront();
    });
    canvas.add(image);
    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

Working example http://jsfiddle.net/px52snx4/